# Google plus.login fails with invalid_scope

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

Why does

```
curl -d "client_id=MYID.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code
```

fail with

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_scope"
}
```

Note that `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` is listed as an appropriate scope, and other things like `plus.me` do work correctly.